# Android marketplace keywords

Tags: android

Just submitted my first app and was surprised to see there was nowhere to enter keywords.How is our app supposed to be found on the marketplace if we can't enter keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search queries are performed on the description body and app name, which makes perfectly sense because if they are "real" keywords for the app they could fit in the description of the app. If it was the other way around, you could place a description "A simple night alarm" and keywords "task manager, game, fun, facebook ... "